# Introducing people

Tags: words

How would you say 'he is...' 'she is...' about other people, in regards to naming them? 
And how would you say:'they are'(meaning people). 
E.g: 'They are my friends.', 'They are my teachers.', 'They are my family.'

Does the phrase 'they are...' change depending on whether 'they' are living or non-living objects, or even if they are male or female?

Answer (score 1):

In journalistic contexts, it's 彼・彼女 for he or she as is mentioned while in everyday conversation, people basically use あの人・この人・その人 for adults and あの子・この子・その子 for young people, after that, あのかた・その方・この方 for people to whom you show your respect and あいつ・こいつ・そいつ for people to whom you don't show your politeness. In addition, attaching たち or ら changes them into "(living) they". However, the plural form of あの方 is あの方々（～かたがた）or あの方たち, not あの方ら, and that of あいつ is あいつら, not あいつたち. It's the same for the rest こ・そ. *edited*

Difference among こ・そ・あ is another complicated problem.

Answer (score 0):

he is...->　彼は
she is...->　彼女は
They are my friends.　->　彼らは私の友達
'they' are living ->彼ら　or non-living　->　これら、それら、あれら